# AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Hello' given input columns

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert some data on a table from pyspark calling a variable but I get the error below when I run it. My table is defined with one column and the data type for that column is string. I hope someone have an answer for this, thanks

'''

```
HORA = "Hello"
spark.sql('''
    INSERT INTO ws_fcd_analitica.cu_portafolio_fenix_bitacora_snap1
    VALUES (''' + HORA + ''')
    ''')
```

'''

error

'''

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve Hello given input columns: []; line 3 pos 12;enter code here
'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [ws_fcd_analitica, cu_portafolio_fenix_bitacora_snap1], [], false, false, false
+- UnresolvedInlineTable [col1], [['Hello]]
```

'''

Comment: The formatted Code you posted looks to me as if your intention was to use three back-ticks ``` instead of three single-quote sequences '''. If so you could correct them by Editing your Question if you want to improve readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because the value you have provided is not enclosed in quotes to be treated as a string and not as a column name change it as below

```
HORA = "Hello"
spark.sql('''
    INSERT INTO ws_fcd_analitica.cu_portafolio_fenix_bitacora_snap1
    VALUES ("''' + HORA + '''")
    ''')
```

same thing with f string

```
HORA = "Hello"
spark.sql(f"""
    INSERT INTO ws_fcd_analitica.cu_portafolio_fenix_bitacora_snap1
    VALUES ('{HORA}')
    """)
```